# Detect time when button was clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, button

I have a form which I need to show the exact time when my button was clicked. How may I "capture" the exact time (hh:mm:ss) when I pressed it?

(please, if the question is duplicated, inform me so I can delete this one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DateTime.Now`:

```
void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Captures the current time in a DateTime object.
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

    // If you need a string, you can use the ToString method.
    string timeString = currentTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime.Now` in your button clicked handler:

```
protected void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime whenClicked = DateTime.Now;
}
```